# Apache wicket: how to update model after validation error

Tags: java, apache, validation, wicket

I have form with dateTimeField, and ListView. 
ListView looks like that:

```
final ListView<String> countryView = new ListView<String>("country", model.<List<String>>bind("country")) {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem<String> item) {
                    final String country = item.getModelObject();
                    item.add(new ValidationDisplayableLabel("country", country, new String[] { modelPath }));
                    item.add(new AjaxLink("deleteLink") {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                            model.getObject().getCountry().remove(country);
                            if (issPeriod) {
                                addButton.setVisible(true);
                                countryTextField.setVisible(true);
                                findButton.setVisible(true);
                            }
                            if (target != null)
                                target.addComponent(rowPanel);
                        }
                    });
            }
        };
        countryTextField = new ValidationDisplayableTextField("countryCodeInput", model.bind("oneCountry"), "job.country.value");

        **countryView.setReuseItems(true);**
        rowPanel.add(countryView);
        rowPanel.add(countryTextField);
        addButton.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        rowPanel.add(addButton);
```

And the addButton looks like that:

```
AjaxSubmitLink addButton = new AjaxSubmitLink(LinkNames.addCountry.toString()) {
        @Override
        public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
            if (model.getObject().getOneCountry() != null)
                addCountry();
                if (target != null)
                    target.addComponent(rowPanel);
                target.addComponent(form.getPage().get("feedbackPanel"));
        }
        @Override
        protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
        {
            onSubmit(target, form);
        }
    };
```

The thing is, that when I fail my dateTimeField (e.g. set hours to 100), enter country code in countryTextField, and press on addButton, it displays validation message in feedback panel, that hour range is incorrect, but don't add the country. This is because my model isn't updated. Maybe there is a way to update it manually? So validation message will be displayed, but the country listView still could be updated?

Submit of the whole form is on other button, so logically it is normal to add a country even if there is a validation error in dateTimeField.

Thanks!

P.S. i've read a lot of posts about similar problem, but most of them were solved with .setReuseItems(true), but it doesn't work in my case.

P.P.S Apache wicket 1.4.17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced a similar problem in my project, the workaround I found was to use a special Visitor. It will update the model even though the submitted input is invalid.

```
public class VisitorUpdateModelWithoutValidation implements FormComponent.IVisitor {

public Object formComponent(IFormVisitorParticipant formComponent) {
        if (formComponent instanceof FormComponent) {
            final FormComponent<?> formComponent1 = (FormComponent<?>) formComponent;
            boolean required = formComponent1.isRequired();
            if (required) {
                formComponent1.setRequired(false);
            }
            formComponent1.modelChanging();
            formComponent1.validate();
            formComponent1.updateModel();
            formComponent1.modelChanged();
            if (required) {
                formComponent1.setRequired(true);
            }
        }

        return Component.IVisitor.CONTINUE_TRAVERSAL;
    }
}
```

Simply use it in the `onSubmit` method of your behavior :  `getForm().visitFormComponents(new VisitorUpdateModelWithoutValidation());`

Comment: To me this feels very broken, not your code but that wicket doesn't update the model unless the form is validated.

Comment: I don't see your point. The purpose of validators is to ensure that model objects don't contain invalid data. Updating them doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Model update restriction is only important if the form is submitted (usually). This wicket behavior not only restricts the model update on submission, but also in any other events. For instance my Check Boxes model updates on other components events would never ever show the current status on screen after a Validation error. For me that is some "Wicked" Wicket behavior.

Answer (score 6):

As an update to this answer, in Wicket 6, you can accomplish this by overriding onError() in the Form:

```
@Override
    protected void onError() {
    super.onError();
    this.updateFormComponentModels();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can issue a `field.clearInput()` on the fields you are updating before you target the update(s).

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks a lot!